# Can we prevent metal corrosion by creating a vacuum around it?

Tags: water

I have a device in a box which has parts of metal. So can I prevent corrosion by creating a vacuum around the metallic object?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word *corrosion* has a range of meanings, but it is generally taken to indicate [the chemical reaction of a material with its environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrosion). For example iron corrodes by reacting with oxygen in the air (or water if it's underwater).

If you put the metal in a vacuum then it doesn't have anything around it to react with, so in this case yes putting the metal in a vacuum will stop it corroding.